# Padding is incorrect. AES Python encryption

Tags: python, encryption, aes, padding, pycryptodome

I'm trying to put together a simple encryption using python.

This is the encrypt:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
BLOCK_SIZE = 32

def encrypt(message):
    obj = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, b'This is an IV456')
    return obj.encrypt(pad(message, BLOCK_SIZE))
```

Encryption seems to work as it returns this:

```
b'V=\t7I\x99\xa5\x06*\xa1={\x95+\xc1h\xfeY\xc2\xb5\xcf3F:\x88\xa6g\x94d\x87\xd7U'
```

However for decryption I use:

```
def decrypt(ciphertext):
    obj2 = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, b'This is an IV456')
    return obj2.decrypt(unpad(ciphertext, BLOCK_SIZE))
```

But it shows:

> Padding is incorrect

This is the entire file I'm trying to put together:

```
import sys
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import importlib
try:
    importlib.import_module('psutil')
except ImportError:
    import pip
    pip.main(['install', 'psutil'])
finally:
    globals()['psutil'] = importlib.import_module('psutil')

def collect_stats():
    try:
        cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
        memory = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
        disk = psutil.disk_usage('/').percent
        str_to_send_back = "{} {} {}".format(cpu, memory, disk)
        str_to_send_back = str_to_send_back.encode()
        str_to_send_back = encrypt(str_to_send_back)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Oops this error happened in collect_stats() inside client.py: ' + str(e))


def encrypt(message):
    obj = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, b'This is an IV456')
    return obj.encrypt(message)


def decrypt(ciphertext):
    obj2 = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    return obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    collect_stats()
```

Comment: Umm... You encrypted with `CBC` mode, and decrypted with `CFB` mode. Even if you hadn't messed up the padding, this would be broken. Moreover, `CFB` mode makes `AES` usable as a stream cipher (so it works on any number of bytes, not just blocks of 16), so if you'd used it consistently, you wouldn't need to pad or unpad at all.

Comment: BLOCK_SIZE 32 cannot be the case it's AES (so must be 16).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When encrypting, you do the padding then the encryption:

```
obj.encrypt(pad(message, BLOCK_SIZE))
```

This would lead me to believe that when decrypting, you should decrypt first, unpad later. So:

```
obj2.decrypt(unpad(ciphertext, BLOCK_SIZE))
```

would become:

```
unpad(obj2.decrypt(ciphertext), BLOCK_SIZE)
```

Comment: `BLOCK_SIZE` appears to be an argument to `unpad()`, not `decrypt()`. Otherwise, this is the same impression I got.

Comment: @glibdud woops! now fixed